# It may not have\has been delivered yet

Tags: modal-verbs

I came across this sentence:

> "**It** may not **have** been delivered yet"

I can't understand: why is "have" used here with "it"?

Comment: Maulik, what he probably means is why *it* doesn't cause *have* to turn into its third-person singular form, *has*: "It may not **has** been delivered yet".

Comment: what is the source?

Comment: Okay, that's because of *may*. It takes *have* and never *has*.

Comment: _"why is 'have' used here with 'it'"_ It's not! "May" is used here with "it". "Have" is used here with "may". Read _all_ the words

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> "**It** may not **have** been delivered yet"

The sentence uses **have** instead of **has** because the verb *to have* is attached here to **may**, a [modal verb](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/auxiliary.htm). When we have a construction of the type `modal verb + another verb`, we put the second verb in the infinitive form (without *to*):

> She **goes** to the dentist today.

but

> She **may go** (not *may goes*!) to the dentist today. (*go* is used in the infinitive form without *to*).

Comment: Thanks for saving my efforts, I deleted my answer halfway! +1 :)

Comment: Well, Hindi Russi bhai bhai. (0:

Comment: hey...wow.. you know a bit of it or the whole language? :) nice to hear that anyway!

Comment: Only this phrase. (0; Oh, and namaste, of course! My sister knows more, she had her Master's degree from JNU.